# Android: Getting instance of my Activity from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have Activity and Fragment.

I can access Activity using method getActivity();
But it's instance of FragmentActivity. How can I get instance of my Activity?

I tried it: `((MyActivity) getActivity())`

It works but I think it's not the best way to do it.
Is there more good ways?

Comment: What kind of method do you think is the best one?

Comment: getActivity() is the instance of the activity which started the fragment

Answer (score 0):

> Following ways are there.

1. In onCreateView have catch the reference of the view , then view.getContext();
2. getView() can be used, getContext() concept;